# Submission of a jsp page after a particular time interval

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I have used setTimeout method to do this and passed a variable which contains time but my settimeout method takes only the initialized value of that variable and not the value that is fetched from database.

Here is my code:

```
  <html>  
        <head>  
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
            <title>Givetest</title>  

             <script type = "text/javascript">  
             function submitForm() {  
                 document.forms[0].submit();  
             }  
             </script>  

             <script language="JavaScript" src="http://scripts.hashemian.com/js/countdown.js"></script>  
        </head>  
        <%  
            String ts=request.getParameter("testname");  
            session.setAttribute("tname", ts);  
            Connection con=null;  
            Statement s1=null;  
            Statement s=null;  
            ResultSet r1=null;  
            ResultSet r=null;  
            int t=120000;  
            String time=null;  
            try  
            {  
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");  
                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:online_testing");  
                s=con.createStatement();   
                s1=con.createStatement();          
                r=s.executeQuery("select * from "+ts+"");     
                r1=s1.executeQuery("select duration from tests where testname="+ts+"");    
                if(r1.next())  
                {  
                    time=r1.getString("duration");  
                    t=Integer.parseInt(time)*60000;  
logger.info(time);           
                } 
else {
   logger.info("No row found in db for test " + ts);
          System.out.println("No row found in db for test " + ts);
           out.println("<br>!! <b>No row found in db </b>for test " + ts + "<br><br><br>");         
}      
      r1.close();  
      }  
            catch(Exception e1)  
            {  
                response.setContentType("text/html");  
                out.println(e1.toString());  
            }  
        %>  
        <body onload="setTimeout('submitForm()',<%=t%>)">      

        <div class="header"></div>  
            <div class="view" style="color: #050505">  
                <form action="Givetest" method="post">   
                    <h1 align="center" style="color: #050505"><%=ts%></h1>  

                    <%  
                        int i=1;  
                        while(r.next()){  
                        String a = r.getString("question");  
                        String b = r.getString("option1");  
                        String c = r.getString("option2");  
                        String d = r.getString("option3");                                              
                        String e = r.getString("option4");                                                              
                    %>  
                    Question <%=i%>:- <label> <%=a%></label><br>  
                    <input type="radio" name="r<%=i%>" value="<%=b%>" checked><label><%=b%></label><br>  
                    <input type="radio" name="r<%=i%>" value="<%=c%>"><label><%=c%></label><br>  
                    <input type="radio" name="r<%=i%>" value="<%=d%>"><label><%=d%></label><br>  
                    <input type="radio" name="r<%=i%>" value="<%=e%>"><label><%=e%></label><br>  
    <br>  
                    <input type="hidden" name="h" value="<%=ts%>">  

                    <%  
                        i++;  
                        }  
                        r.close();  
                        s.close();  
                        con.close();  
                    %>  
                    <input type="submit" class="button">  
                </form>  
                </div>  
            <div class="copyright" align="center"> © SAUMYARAJ ZALA</div>  
        </body>  
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <body onload="setTimeout('submitForm()',<%=t%>)">
```

You are giving the value only once. DO you  mean it gets value

```
 int t=120000;
```

and not what is in data base? If so are you sure no error is being thrown?

By the way this is not the best way to write a web app - all in jsp - though it works, better is to make servlets and POJOs/ helper .java files for data base etc. Make sure your tomcat/ app server's temp folder are cleaned every time you restart - to make sure its taking latest jsp.

In jsp can have a text like 'Version 001' and increase that manually so your sure correct code version is running.

---

Use loggers or system.out.println if you do not have logger

```
    r1=s1.executeQuery("select duration from tests where testname="+ts+"");    
       //if should be enough as you will only have 0 or 1 row per test? 
       if(r1.next())  
        {  
            time=r1.getString("duration");  
            t=Integer.parseInt(time)*60000;           
        }  else{
           logger.warn("No row found in db for test " + ts);
           //okay for debug
           out.println("<br>!! <b>No row found in db </b>for test " + ts + "<br><br><br>");  
        }
        r1.close();  
    }  
    catch(Exception e1)  
    {  
        response.setContentType("text/html");  
        out.println("<br><br> <b> ERROR</b>" + e1.toString());  
    }
```

sql
     testname="+ts+""

is very bad should use a prepared statement or you are asking for a SQL injection attack. look at owasp https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Actually i want the time interval that this setTimeout method will have to be fetched from a table in a database and for that i made a resultset r1 in my code above and then after fetching that time interval i copied that in variable "t" which was fed to my setTimeout method. This is an online test so my setTimeout will have different time interval for each test.

Comment: that is what i assumed, and  ask : are you seeing any error in the data base look up code? and what is the value of t your getting?

Comment: use debug code in edited answer to see if your data base look up is working

Comment: the result i got is that my variable "t" is taking the value that i initialized i.e 120000 and not the value from our result set

Comment: that you have said many times. i tried to add some code to help you understand why that might be happening - by seeing if there is any error in the data base code or not. the correct way would be to test the database code alone - to see if it is working. you need to read up on logging, and think about how to debug your code ... else hours will be wasted and nothing much gained

Comment: Yes Sir, Exactly as you said I have logged that variable as you can see in my edited code but nothing is getting logged in my output.

Comment: so put a try catch - throwable - might be a class not found error, around full code. first make a regular java class and  catch(Throwable e1)

Comment: thankyou what i did was i made a servlet and fetched records there and placed it under a session variable then in jsp just fetched the record. Is this okay?? The error was in my where clause. Can you tell that why the error was not showing up in jsp?

Comment: not sure what the error was - i think u have missed quotes. but that is the wrong way to code java sql. see https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is in the where clause which should be like:-

```
r1=s1.executeQuery("select duration from tests where testname="+ts+"");
```

Moreover this code should be executed in servlets before it is passed to jsp